# Documentation on Materials and Textures

Tags: texturing, materials

Simple question... Why is there no documentation on how to properly use materials and textures? The only documentation I can find is for loading texture images in the UV editor. The Blender search engine doesn't come up with anything useful at all when you search for "materials" or "textures". This is something that should have its own section in the docs.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with materials or texturing you are trying to work out?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what do you mean by "properly"? If you are referring to a specifical workflow, name it. At the moment the topic is a little broad, and that's probably why it has not still being extensively coverd in the docs. There are lots of things that can be done with textures...

Comment: Blender's new documentation (https://www.blender.org/manual/) is still fairly new and it might be work in progress for a long time. Texturing a model is a fairly extensive topic, since it still has to cover two render engines, different purposes (still images, animations, game assets...). It eventually will cover the basics, but certainly not every aspect for every possible purpose.

Comment: Timaroberts - My question is specific to the Blender docs.

Comment: Carlo - By "properly" I'm using it in the same way that the Blender docs use the word when explaining that there is a Proper way and a Quick way to use UV Texturing. This is just the problem.... I don't understand what the docs mean by saying this. They don't explain and just confuse the issue.

Comment: metaphor_set - I don't believe it. I know how crucial documentation is to maintaining software development.

Comment: Well, it's still quite hard to figure out what you mean exactly. "Old folks" like us don't look into these corners of the Documentation very often, since we've assigned more textures than there are days in our lives.
Maybe you could add a link or a screenshot and highlight the exact problem?

Comment: How do I highlight what's missing?

Comment: Let us know what you're struggling with! BTW You will probably get more help for what you are thinking from tutorials and googling "how to use *some functionality* in Blender".

Comment: How about https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/index.html and https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/index.html?

Comment: Yeah, but that just covers Cycles. I'm looking for an explanation on how to properly use materials and textures in BI. The problem is that the docs are very limited in explaining how to PROPERLY (their word) use them. Why do the docs offer a 'quick way' and a 'proper way', and yet not explain either one very clearly, leaving a person confused?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the answer to your question is "Why no documentation?" is simple. It is free open source software and the developers didn't yet have to time to do it in more details. However, if you have some knowledge in the subject you can contribute:

https://www.blender.org/manual/about/contribute/index.html

If everyone will do so, the documentation soon will be very extensive.

Second, it is true, that the documentation on this topics is not detailed enough. I also didn't necessarily have problems with particular materials, but wanted first to know what materials I can create, how I should do it and what different parameters mean. I found many answers in the article below. It has good explanations and many pictures. Hope it will be useful for you too.

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia/